# VPN (Cisco AnyConnect) openconnect plugin stopped setting up DNS on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, vpn, openconnect

Today (it is 2019-05-19) I can't connect to internal resource within VPN – it worked OK the day before. It happens because DNS doesn't resolve internal names.

systemd-resolve shows this

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 4 (vpn0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 3 (docker0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 2 (enp3s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.254
                      fe80::1
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

What can it be? VPN problem? Ubuntu updates? I updated something yesterday, didn't even care what exactly.

Ubuntu 18.04 BTW. Default IPv4 parameters: DHCP, etc.

UPD it looks like DNS servers are here. It is yet another systemd-resolve issue:

```
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8897] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",0]: VPN connection: (IP Config Get) reply received.
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8915] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: VPN connection: (IP4 Config Get) reply received
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8922] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data: VPN Gateway: ★★★.★★★.★★★.★★
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8922] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data: Tunnel Device: "vpn0"
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8922] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data: IPv4 configuration:
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8922] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Internal Address: 10.5.0.81
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8922] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Internal Prefix: 24
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8922] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Internal Point-to-Point Address: 10.5.0.81
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8922] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.121.0.0/16   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8923] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.1.0.0/16   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8923] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.200.0.0/16   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8923] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.90.0.0/16   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8923] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.136.156.0/26   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8923] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 62.76.112.14/32   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8923] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 62.76.112.20/32   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8923] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.5.0.0/24   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8923] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 62.76.112.15/32   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8923] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 62.76.112.13/32   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8923] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 172.22.0.0/16   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8923] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 172.21.0.0/16   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8923] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.160.0.0/16   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8924] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 192.168.100.0/24   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8924] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 172.20.0.0/16   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8924] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.20.0.0/16   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8925] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.140.1.0/24   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8925] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.130.0.0/16   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8925] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.7.0.0/16   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8925] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.110.0.0/16   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8925] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.80.1.0/24   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8925] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.120.0.0/16   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8925] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.100.0.0/16   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8925] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.150.1.0/24   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8925] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.170.0.0/16   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8925] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Static Route: 10.5.0.0/24   Next Hop: 0.0.0.0
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8925] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Internal DNS: 10.110.1.2
… NetworkManager[1015]: <info>  [1558277941.8925] vpn-connection[0x5647781d64c0,e7c29208-dec3-4b54-969f-6ef43b29a502,"Job",4:(vpn0)]: Data:   Internal DNS: 10.100.1.3
```

Comment: Your VPN isn't working. Reboot and see if that fixes things. Else edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: @heynnema
The VPN is working actually: `host <internal addr> 10.100.1.3` returns actual internal IP address. It is upper, DNS user space utilities that don't work.

So, `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` gives `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 фев  3 22:20 /etc/resolv.conf ->  ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`


And `cat /etc/resolv.conf` returns lots of comments and these two lines:


`nameserver 127.0.0.53`
`options edns0`

Comment: I see no 10.100.1.3 showing as a VPN DNS server in your `systemd-resolve  --status` command. I don't think your VPN is working correctly. Test with dnsleak.com. Try a new symlink for /etc/resolv.conf. Delete /etc/resolv.conf (`sudo rm -i /etc/resolv.conf`), and then `sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`. Reboot. See if it works better with and without VPN.

Comment: @heynnema no, doesn't work at all with that symlink

Comment: @heynnema thank you very much for help BTW

Comment: Then try `sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`. Report back.

Comment: This doesn't help either. Still no DNS from VPN.

Comment: With the setting as in my last comment, and VPN up, show me `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `systemd-resolve --status`.

Comment: `systemd-resolve --status` http://oneclickpaste.com/6390/ and `cat /etc/resolve.conf` is http://oneclickpaste.com/6391/

Comment: There are 3 different possibilities for symlinks for /etc/resolv.conf. I'm expecting to see 127.0.0.53, and possibly a DNS server address like 10.110.1.2 and 10.100.1.3 (if VPN is up). You may have edited a couple of other files to give the 192.168.1.254 and ipv6 address.

Comment: I actually tried but remove that lines. And my initial post here: it was that `192.168.1.254` (my router IP address). I didn't touch anything system before that.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: @heynnema no problem. In a week I will solve the problem. The bad thing I am right on the deadline these days LOL ))

Comment: If you care to, please let me know what you find.

Comment: @heynnema the reason was buggy network-manager update. Downgrading to the previous version resolved this.

Comment: Thanks for the update. How did you find it? I'm on 19.04 and that's why I didn't see the same problem. Another reason to upgrade :-)

Comment: I'd love to see your `systemd-resolve --status` now.

Comment: @heynnema It almost exactly like what I did post in a question. Except it doesn't have the very last line `          DNS Domain: ~.`.  Found solution here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1829838. They say network-manager 1.12 doesn't have this problem. Would prefer to stay with the LTS as it is practically the first serious problem I had with 18.04 so far BTW :)

Comment: I still think that the VPN DNS servers should show up in the `systemd-resolve --status` command. Anyway, I'm glad you found a fix for it.